# Error injecting mybatis mapper in spring using Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, spring-mybatis

I configure it like this in the `application-context.xml`

```
<mybatis:scan base-package="com.db"/>
```

And add `@Component` for the mapper interface.

```
@Component
public interface MenuMapper {}
```

And autowire it like this.

```
@Autowired
MenuMapper menuMapper;
```

It generates errors in IDEA.
The error is

> No beans of type MenuMapper found.

Comment: the erros is No beans of type `MenuMapper` found.

Comment: the erros is No beans of type `MenuMapper` found.

Comment: It's because there isn't an implementation of MenuMapper because Mybatis generates it.  Did you ever find a way to ignore in this in intellij without putting annotations on every mapping?

Answer (score 1):

Add @Repository to your MenuMapper interface

Answer (score 0):

This because mybatis set bean definition class as `MapperFactoryBean`, so it's not able to find type of mapper. You can use `@Resource` replace `@Autowired`. See `ClassPathMapperScanner` for detail.